# Initialising a set through spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a class A which contain the following

```
class A
{

private HashSet<Long> at = new HashSet<Long>();
```

and it has a constructor like this

```
A()
{
//set is being initialsised here 

                this.at.add(new Long(44));
        this.at.add(new Long(34));
        this.at.add(new Long(54));
        this.at.add(new Long(55));


}
```

now please advise how can I initialize this hashset of Long type through Spring,,

I have tried ...

```
<property name="at">
            <util:set set-class="java.util.HashSet">
                <value>45</value>
                <value>65</value>
                <value>87</value>
            </util:set>
        </property>
```

Comment: Have you tried something before posting the question?

Comment: [This link](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) will help you

Answer (score 3):

```
private HashSet<Long> at;
```

And try this (make sure you have setter for `at`)

```
<bean class="path.A">
   <property name="at">
      <set>
         <value>44</value>
         <value>34</value>
         <value>54</value>
         <value>55</value>
      </set>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: the hashset is of long type and the way you have shown is wil make 44,34,54,55 as string

Comment: @tuntunwretee : don't worry about that, just try this solution

Comment: @Alex can we use.. <bean type="java.lang.Long" or something please advise

Comment: @tuntun wretee I think you could try to use `<util:constant static-field="...">` instead.